# What is the API for iPhone/iPad file transfer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

I can't seem to find anywhere the name of the API to use in my iPad(iOS 3.2) app in order to be able to sync files from/to computer using iTunes, the way Stanza, GoodReader and zillion other iPad apps do. 
Any ideas? Hints? Tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: [File-Sharing Support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW11).

Comment: I just went to the Apple Developer site and searched for "File Sharing", first result with an iPhone icon on the left was the link above :) Good luck with implementing it in your app ;)

Comment: This link is broken. A working link is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30